# Passing class into an object that is a variable inside that class

Tags: php

Basically, I have a Fuyukai.class.php file which contains this code:

```
class Fuyukai {
    private $configLoader;

    function __construct() {
        $this->configLoader = new ConfigLoader($this);
    }
}
```

And the ConfigLoader has this constructor:

```
class ConfigLoader {
    private $fuyukai;

    function __construct($fuyukai)
    {
        $this->fuyukai = $fuyukai;
    }
}
```

Is this correct? I need some kind of global class, but I don't really know how to do it and this "solution" was the most natural solution that came into my mind.

Comment: You're code seem right to me, you could see this topic to make you code better. Type Hindting http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php

Comment: it is fine. people do this all the time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code looks fine, the only thing I would add is this:

```
class ConfigLoader {
    private $fuyukai;

    //make sure only Fuyukai objects can be passed through constructor
    function __construct(Fuyukai $fuyukai)
    {
        $this->fuyukai = $fuyukai;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, I haven't know about this one. Thank you.